# Java Writing to the Same txt File On Different Lines

Tags: java, file, lines

I dont have any worthwhile code to show but I am trying to understand the concept.

I am opening a text file in two classes, one time saves a username like "user242," and the other class saves a number "42421,". The way I have set this out it saves on different lines such as:

line: 1 - user242,
line: 2 -42421,

But every time I run the classes again it doesnt go in the format:
line: 1 - user242, user114,
line: 2 - 42421, 42525

It instead messes up and goes:

line: 1 - user242,
line: 2 - 42421, user114,
line: 3 - 4252

I think this is because of my use in newLine();
so is this any way I can fix this so it writes one variable always to the top line and the second always to the second line?

Comment: This is not the right way if your app is multi threaded. Your not posting code so people can only guess what is happening! if its only one thraed - add a new line after writing user or number. If its multi threaded then you need a sperate synchronized object to rec and write to the file on one thread so it does not mess up.

Answer (score 0):

you can't insert data into a file. you can overwrite data using `RandomAccessFile` though. open the file, read the contents, modify and write them back.

you can also look at this [Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/randomaccessfile.html)